# Lapply to the list of data frames in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply

```
> df1 <- data.frame(A = 1:10, B= 11:20)
> df2 <- data.frame(A = 21:30, B = 31:40)
> ddata <- list(df1,df2)
```

My objective is to perform correlation of A column and B column per data frame of the list.
i.e.

```
cor (ddata[[1]]$A,ddata[[1]]$B)
cor (ddata[[2]]$A,ddata[[2]]$B)
```

for this I am using `lapply` but I am doing something incorrect, please help.

```
lapply(ddata, cor)
```

Comment: Try `lapply(ddata,function(x){
  cor(x[[1]],x[[2]])
})`

Comment: Hi, Thanks your solution worked, but i have a doubt.

When I refer to x[[1]] in the function, it refers to the entire data frame right.. Then how does it perform cor between individual columns of the data frame ??

Comment: I added an answer below to elaborate on my comment a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with your code is that when you call `cor` on a whole `data.frame` (of all numeric columns), it will return a correlation *matrix*, containing the pairwise correlations of all columns - with the values on the diagonals being the respective column's correlation with itself (which is always equal to 1.00). This wouldn't be immediately apparent with your sample data, since `cor(A,B) == cor(B,A) == cor(A,A) == cor(B,B) == 1` for your two `data.frame`s. This is clearer in the following example:

```
df5 <- data.frame(A=rnorm(10),B=rnorm(10),C=rnorm(10))
R> cor(df5)
           A           B          C
A 1.00000000  0.05131293  0.6173047
B 0.05131293  1.00000000 -0.1312331
C 0.61730466 -0.13123314  1.0000000
```

Regardless, I think you were looking for a single correlation *value* rather than a correlation *matrix*, which can be achieved a couple of different ways - accessing the `data.frame`'s columns using either `x[,1]` & `x[,2]` or using `x[[1]]` & `x[[2]]`.

Additionally, there is another syntax option; one which results in a scalar value for correlation, except unlike the two cases above, it preserves the `matrix` class. This is accessing the columns using `x[1]` & `x[2]`, since the single brackets (with no comma) will yield a one column `data.frame`.

For your purposes, any of the 3 methods noted directly above should be acceptable - as long as you pass `cor` two objects, whether they are (atomic) numeric vectors (case `[, ]` and case `[[ ]]`) or *single* column `data.frame`s (case `[ ]`) - the function will evaluate as `cor(x, y, ...)` and return a single correlation *value*. The (subtle) difference between the first two methods and the third method is the class of the return value - `numeric` (atomic) for the former, and `matrix` for the latter - but this is most likely an inconsequential detail in the big picture.

---

Let me summarize this with a couple of examples, using this data:

```
set.seed(123)
df3 <- data.frame(
  A=rnorm(10),
  B=rnorm(10))
##
set.seed(321)
df4 <- data.frame(
  A=rnorm(10),
  B=rnorm(10))
##
dflist <- list(df3,df4)
```

---

A. Result type is a correlation matrix; result class is `matrix`:

```
R> class(cor(df3)); cor(df3)
[1] "matrix"
          A         B
A 1.0000000 0.5776151
B 0.5776151 1.0000000
```

B. Result type is a single correlation value; result class is `matrix`:

```
R> class(cor(df3[1],df3[2])); cor(df3[1],df3[2])
[1] "matrix"
          B
A 0.5776151
```

C. Result type is a single correlation value; result class is `numeric`:

```
R> class(cor(df3[,1],df3[,2])); cor(df3[,1],df3[,2])
[1] "numeric"
[1] 0.5776151
```

D. Result type is a single correlation value; result class is `numeric`:

```
R> class(cor(df3[[1]],df3[[2]])); cor(df3[[1]],df3[[2]])
[1] "numeric"
[1] 0.5776151
```

---

Similarly, the following four functions `fA` - `fD` correspond to the cases `A` - `D` described above:

```
fA <- function(y) {
  res <- lapply(y,cor)
  message(paste0("Element class: ",class(res[[1]])))
  res
}
##
fB <- function(y) {
  res <- lapply(y, function(x) {
    cor(x[1],x[2])
  })
  message(paste0("Element class: ",class(res[[1]])))
  res
}
##
fC <- function(y) {
  res <- lapply(y, function(x) {
    cor(x[,1],x[,2])
  })
  message(paste0("Element class: ",class(res[[1]])))
  res
}
##
fD <- function(y) {
  res <- lapply(y, function(x) {
    cor(x[[1]],x[[2]])
  })
  message(paste0("Element class: ",class(res[[1]])))
  res
}
```

And running them on the object `dflist` gives us

```
R> fA(dflist)
Element class: matrix
[[1]]
          A         B
A 1.0000000 0.5776151
B 0.5776151 1.0000000

[[2]]
           A          B
A  1.0000000 -0.1816951
B -0.1816951  1.0000000

##
R> fB(dflist)
Element class: matrix
[[1]]
          B
A 0.5776151

[[2]]
           B
A -0.1816951

##
R> fC(dflist)
Element class: numeric
[[1]]
[1] 0.5776151

[[2]]
[1] -0.1816951

##
R> fD(dflist)
Element class: numeric
[[1]]
[1] 0.5776151

[[2]]
[1] -0.1816951
```

Comment: Also I didn't address it above, but using the column access operator `$`, such as `df3$A`, is equivalent to using `df3[,1]` or `df3[[1]]` (or `df3[,"A"]` or `df3[["A"]]`).